# Flutter Navegação entre telas, fica escuro

Tags: android, flutter

Eu clico no botão Cadastre-se, e ele chama a outra tela. Já na outra tela tem o botão Registrar, que ao clicar não retorna para tela. Fica tudo escuro. Tentei várias coisas com o Navigator.pop(context) e sem sucesso. No caso queria remover a tela da pilha, fazendo com que retorne para a Tela login depois de cadastrado.

```
class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      body: SingleChildScrollView(

        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                end: Alignment.bottomRight,

                colors:[
                  //   Color(0xFF8A2387),
                  //   Color(0xFFE94057),
                  //   Color(0xFFF27121),

                  Color(0xFFfbba00),
                  Color(0xFFfbba00),
                  Color(0xFFF0E68C),


                ]
            ),
          ),

          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 22),
              Image.asset('images/logo.png'),

              Container(
                height: 520,
                width: 325,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                ),

                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(height: 30),

                    Text('Aplicativo',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 35,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                      ),
                    ),

                    SizedBox(height: 20),

                    Container(
                      width: 250,
                      child: TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Email',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          suffixIcon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.envelope,
                            size: 17,),

                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    Container(
                      width: 250,
                      child: TextField(
                        obscureText: true,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Senha',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          suffixIcon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.eyeSlash,
                            size: 17,),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),



                    

  

 // ************************   BLOCO DO BOTÃO CADASTRE-SE **********************
 // ************************          INÍCIO              *********************

                    SizedBox(height: 30,),   // QUEBRA DE LINHA
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: (){ 
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => RegistroPage()));
       
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        width: 250,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                              begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              end: Alignment.centerRight,
                              colors:[


                                Color(0xFFfbba00),
                                Color(0xFFFFD700),

                                Color(0xFFFFFF00),

                              ]
                          ),
                        ),

                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                          child: Text('Cadastre-se ',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                            ),

                          ),
                        ),

                      ),
                    ),
// ********************************************************************************************* //
// ************************   FIM DO BLOCO DO BOTÃO CADASTRE-SE ******************************* //


                    SizedBox(height: 25),
                    Text('Login Com Redes Sociais',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),

                    SizedBox(height: 10),

                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.instagram,color: Colors.pinkAccent[700], size: 40),
                        Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.facebookF,color: Colors.blue[700],size: 40),
                        Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.twitter,color: Colors.lightBlueAccent[700],size: 40),
                      ],
                    ),

                  ],
                ),

              ),

            ],
          ),

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Tela de registro:

```
class RegistroPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const RegistroPage({Key key, String title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.yellow,
      ),

      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,

      home: const RegistroPage2(title: 'CADASTRO'),
    );
  }
}

class RegistroPage2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegistroPage2({Key key,  this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;


  @override
  State<RegistroPage2> createState() => _RegistroPage2State();
}

class _RegistroPage2State extends State<RegistroPage2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)  {


    return Scaffold(

      body: SingleChildScrollView(

        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                end: Alignment.bottomRight,

                colors:[

                  Color(0xFFfbba00),
                  Color(0xFFfbba00),
                  Color(0xFFF0E68C),


                ]
            ),
          ),

    child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [


      SizedBox(height: 48),

      Container(

        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
              end: Alignment.centerRight,
              colors:[

                Color(0xFFfbba00),
                Color(0xFFFFD700),

                Color(0xFFFFFF00),

              ]
          ),
        ),

      ),

      // ******************************   BLOCO DO BOTÃO CADASTRAR *************************** //
      // ******************************          INÍCIO        ************************** //


      SizedBox(height: 48),
      GestureDetector(

        onTap: (){

         Navigator.pop(context);
        },

        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          width: 350,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                end: Alignment.centerRight,
                colors:[


                  Color(0xFFFFFF00),
                  Color(0xFFFFD700),
                  Color(0xFFFFFF00),

                ]
            ),
          ),

          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            child: Text('Cadastrar',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
              ),

            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),



      // ****************************      FIM            ********************************************* //
// ************************   FIM DO BOTÃO CADASTRAR  ************************************** //              
    ],
        
        ),
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu problema é relacionado ao widget ***RegistroPage***.

Ao criar um novo widget, você não precisa incluir um *MaterialApp* no mesmo, pois esse widget é comum utilizarmos apenas 1x na aplicação (Normalmente no main), pois ele é quem vai controlar a navegação, rotas e outras coisas.
Para sua navegação funcionar corretamente, basta chamar direto o ***RegistroPage2***.

### O problema

```
class RegistroPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const RegistroPage({Key key, String title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp( <---- Esse widget aqui
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.yellow,
      ),

      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,

      home: const RegistroPage2(title: 'CADASTRO'),
    );
  }
}
```

### A solução

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => RegistroPage2(title: "CADASTRO")));
```

> Se o intuito de utilizar o widget *RegistroPage* for criar uma tela
> para aninhar outras telas, baste você remover o *MaterialApp* dela que
> poderá utilizar sem problemas.

Comment: Realmente era o lance do MaterialApp, Eu ia perder muito tempo com isso. Preciso compreender mais alguns conceitos. Muito obrigado de verdade. resolveu